# How to find specific information stored in json data format in weather API

Tags: json, swift, weather-api

I'm writing a Swift project to get weather data from a weather API, Wunderground. Now I can extract information such as temperature or the relative humidity, but I'm getting trouble on getting information stored in the inner list of a nested list using swift. For example, I cannot get the information of "display_location.state" stored in "current_observation".

Here is the an example of the weather information provided by the Wunderground:

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "conditions": 1
  }
    }
  , "current_observation": {
        "image": {
        "url":"http://icons.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
        "title":"Weather Underground",
        "link":"http://www.wunderground.com"
        },
        "display_location": {
        "full":"San Francisco, CA",
        "city":"San Francisco",
        "state":"CA",
        "state_name":"California",
        "country":"US",
        "country_iso3166":"US",
        "zip":"94101",
        "magic":"1",
        "wmo":"99999",
        "latitude":"37.77500916",
        "longitude":"-122.41825867",
        "elevation":"47.00000000"
        },
        "temperature_string":"76.3 F (24.6 C)",
        "relative_humidity":"43%",
    }
}
```

Here is my Swift code on extracting weather information:

```
var url = NSURL(string:"http://api.wunderground.com/api/56968011acc3e3eb/conditions/q/\(state)/\(city).json")
var data = NSData.dataWithContentsOfURL(url, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error: nil)
var str = NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
var json:AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)
var weatherInfo:AnyObject! = json.objectForKey("current_observation")
var currentTemp: AnyObject! = weatherInfo.objectForKey("temperature_string")
var humidity:AnyObject! = weatherInfo.objectForKey("relative_humidity")
var wind:AnyObject! = weatherInfo.objectForKey("wind_kph")
display.text = "Temperature: \(currentTemp)\nHumidity: \(humidity)\nWind: \(wind)\n"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick note on style, you should use `let` instead of `var` any time you are not going to change the value of your variable after it is set the first time.

The only thing that doesn't look right is how you'r pulling the sub objects out of the JSON. Keep in mind that the data structures in the JSON look like this

```
NSDictionary {
    "response": NSDictionary {},
    "current_observation": NSDictionary {
          "relative_humidity": NSString
          ...
    }
    ...
}
```

So when you pull the objects such as `current_observation` out, you need to make sure you cast things to the proper objects

```
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:nil) as NSDictionary
let weatherInfo = json["current_observation"] as NSDictionary
let currentTemp = weatherInfo["temperature_string"] as NSString
...
```

Although to be perfectly honest, for something like this, I would recommend using [EasyMapping](https://github.com/EasyMapping/EasyMapping). Then you can just set up swift classes to represent the JSON, and a map provider so you can just do something like

```
if let weatherInfo = EKMapper.objectFromExternalRepresentation(json, withMapping:/*mapping provider*/) {
    //do stuff
}
```

and then you have it all deserialized from the JSON into swift objects. This also prevents the app from crashing if the JSON structure changes or is missing values that you expect to be there.